# Enviar data pelo $_GET

Tags: ajax, get

Estou precisando enviar uma data pelo `$_GET` porém não estou conseguindo, qual é o método para fazer esta passagem ?

O envio está assim:

```
ajax/deletaPessoaVinculo.php?dt=2016-01-29&amp;p=PV&amp;a=1&amp;pb=3&amp;c=SUPRV
```

E o `array` está ficando assim:

```
Array ( [:COD_TIPOX_VINCU] => SUPRV [:COD_IDENT_PESSO] => 3 [:DAT_INICI_VINCU] => 116122144423521 [:igj] => ibhr )
```

Estou montando meu HTML assim:

```
. '<td><a class="ajax-link" href="ajax/deletaPessoaVinculo.php?dt='. dataDeDMAParaAMD($vinculo->DAT_INICI_VINCU) .'&p=PV&a=1&pb=' . $w_COD_IDENT_PESSO . '&c=' . $vinculo->COD_TIPOX_VINCU . '"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>'
```

E para receber :

```
$w_DAT_INICI_VINCU = ( isset($_GET['dt']) ? $_GET['dt'] : "" );
```

A minha função dataDeDMAParaAMD simplesmente coloca a data da forma que o servidor consiga salvar, descrita abaixo:

```
<?php

if (!function_exists('eglise_dataDeDMAParaAMD')) {

    function eglise_dataDeDMAParaAMD($p_data) {

        return (strlen($p_data) === 10 ? substr($p_data, 6, 4) . '-' . substr($p_data, 3, 2) . '-' . substr($p_data, 0, 2) : (strlen($p_data) === 0 ? null : $p_data));
    }

}
```

Defino o array neste momento:

```
function deletaUnico($w_pagina) {
global $suc, $w_COD_TIPOX_VINCU, $conexao;

$campos = array();

$campos[':COD_TIPOX_VINCU'] = $_GET['c'];
$campos[':COD_IDENT_PESSO'] = $_GET['pb'];
$campos[':DAT_INICI_VINCU']= $_GET['dt'];
$campos[':igj'] = $suc->getCOD_IDENT();
error_log($_GET['dt']); //Aqui ja aparece o numero todo maluco
    $sqlDIV = "DELETE FROM"
        . " tbl_IGREJA_VINCULOS"
        . " WHERE"
        . " and COD_TIPOX_VINCU = :COD_TIPOX_VINCU"
        . " and COD_IDENT_PESSO = :COD_IDENT_PESSO"
        . " and DAT_INICI_VINCU = :DAT_INICI_VINCU";

error_log(print_r($campos));

try {
    $conexao->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
    $conexao->atualiza($sqlDIV, $campos);

    $conexao->getConnection()->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {

    $conexao->getConnection()->rollback();

    die('ERRO AO ATUALIZAR BANCO DE DADOS');

    error_log('vinculoUpd.php: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54196/discussion-on-question-by-renan-rodrigues-enviar-data-pelo-get)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode enviar a data com as barras normalmente, porém, as barras devem ser substituídas pela sua versão codificada (%2F). Assim, a sua requisição deveria ser:

```
ajax/deletaPessoaVinculo.php?dt=2016%2F01%2F29&amp;p=PV&amp;a=1&amp;pb=3&amp;c=SUPRV
```

Comment: Mais sobre o conteúdo após a interrogação (parâmetros de query) : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string